# How can I change font attributes for "Text Entry" in Glade

Tags: application-development, fonts, gtk, glade

I'd like to change font attributes (size, style, family, colour) for `Text Entry` but I don't see any option for this in Glade. There's no problem with `Label`, but `Label` is not editable by user. 
I tried to edit the `MyAppNameWindow.ui` file in Gedit and copied `attributes` from `Label` to `Text Entry` but after that the app does not start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how to do this using Glade. However, this is simple to achieve using a small piece of code.

I assume you are using `quickly`, and thus you write in Python.

- First, you need to import Pango library (it comes by default with Gtk)

  `from gi.repository import Pango`
- Then, assuming your entry widget is called **`myentry`**:

  `myentry.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Sans Bold 12'))`

Adjust the above to your needs, and remember place that instruction somewhere in initialization code, so that it gets executed just after the window is constructed.

I hope such non-Glade solution will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. I tried before with `import pango` but got some error.